# Configuring default alsa device (hw:0,0) in asoundrc

Tags: audio, alsa

I am using a multimedia application (XBMC Frodo RC3) that does not allow me to select custom pcm device. It just asks the hardware device (in this case it is hw:0,0).

Given this limitation I have to write an asoundrc (or asound.conf) file where I can configure the hw:0,0 device.

I test the configuration by running:

```
    speaker-test -D hw:0,0 -c6
```

This simulates how the XBMC will produce surround sound.

My asound.conf looks like this at the moment:

```
pcm.surroundsw {
    type    route
    slave {
            pcm surround51
    }
    ttable {
            0.2 1
            1.3 1
            2.1 8
            3.0 8
            4.4 1
            5.5 1
    }
 }
```

This is the working routing table so when I run `speaker-test -Dsurroundsw -c6` I get the desired behavior.

What kind of asound.conf should I write to get the desired behavior when I run `speaker-test -D hw:0,0 -c6`? This is purely an ALSA configuration problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a device named `hw`, but use `!` to ensure that the built-in definition is overridden, and use `@args` to allow parameters (which are ignored if you don't use them in the definition):

```perl
pcm.!hw {
    @args [ CARD DEV SUBDEV ]
    @args.CARD   { type string }
    @args.DEV    { type integer }
    @args.SUBDEV { type integer }
    # normal definition here:
    type route
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking. Unfortunately XBMC still ignores my asound.conf and apparently accesses the sound card from somewhere else. I have to keep digging.